# SpriteKit and SwiftUI. GameScene func not working from UI button

Tags: swiftui, sprite-kit

I have a SKScene presented in a SwiftUI view.
Trying to use SwiftUI buttons to add a Spritenode to the scene with a simple function.

If I run the function from the GameScene it works fine of course.

But if I try to access the function from the SwiftUI button nothing happens. The function runs (Print"image tapped" is in debug window) but the Sprite does not appear.

Why is this and how do I fix that?

My code

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        
        
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
        //ball()
        
    }
    
    func ball() {
        
        let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 30)
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        ball.fillColor = .blue
        self.addChild(ball)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = GameScene()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 800, height: 930)
        scene.scaleMode = .fill
        scene.backgroundColor = .red
        
        return scene
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button {
                    let makeBall = GameScene()
                    makeBall.ball()
                            print("Image tapped!")
                        } label: {
                            Image("playButton")
                                
                    }
                
                Button {
                            print("Image tapped!")
                        } label: {
                            Image("pauseButton")
                               
                    }
                
                
            }
            SpriteView(scene: scene)
                .frame(width: 800, height: 930, alignment: .center)
            
        }
        
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Your `scene` is a computed property so you are recreating the scene *every* time you try use it in `SpriteView`.
2. You are creating a *new* scene when you try add the ball. This should be added to the *current* scene, not a new instance.

Change `scene` to this:

```
let scene: GameScene = {
    let scene = GameScene()
    scene.size = CGSize(width: 800, height: 930)
    scene.scaleMode = .fill
    scene.backgroundColor = .red

    return scene
}()
```

And change the action on the pause button to this:

```
scene.ball()
print("Image tapped!")
```

Side note: with a fixed scene size like this, you got to be careful - you can only really see the play/pause buttons on iPad screens since the scene size is so big. Consider keeping it at a specific aspect ratio instead, then fitting it to the screen.

Comment: Amazing thank you. Not only did that answer my question but has I thin given me a deeper understanding of what's going on.
Swift did make me adjust the action you suggested to:

scene.ball(scene: scene)

as it was missing an argument in the call. Not entirely sure why it required that but it works!

Comment: Thank you! But you don't want to call it like `scene.ball(scene: scene)`, you are already calling it on the scene. Why did you need to try that? Your `ball()` method takes no parameters, so it shouldn't change to that. And it's unnecessary, since in that function `self` and `scene` will both be the same. Remove the `scene` argument, because `self` already is that.

Comment: if I don't I get this error:

Missing argument for parameter 'scene' in call

Comment: @Waterboy Your original code doesn't have that parameter. If you go to the definition of `ball(...)`, you can remove that (so the parameters are empty) and just use `self` in the method instead. `self` is already implicit, so you also don't next to explicitly use it like for `addChild(...)`.

Comment: Ah. Right sorry I'd left a parameter in the ball() function by mistake from when I was trying ideas to fix earlier. Your code works fine without it now. Great!